# Getting the error: The CLASS variable has more than two levels in SAS for a ttest

Tags: sas

Code:

```
data students;
infile 'C:\Users\Nicolas\Downloads\PERMDATA\PERMDATA\445-dataset.csv' dsd
firstobs=2;
input ID$ Name$ Age GPA Major$ Study_Hours Preference$ Program_Satisfaction Teacher_Satisfaction Credits;
run;

proc ttest data=students alpha=0.95;
class Teacher_Satisfaction;
var gpa;
run;
```

[image: Here is the dataset]

Comment: Why are you trying to run a TTEST using a variable that has more than two levels?  What is the analysis you are trying to do?

Comment: The error is correct, the TTEST is designed for only two levels and your variable TeacherSatisfaction has several levels. If you want to test across multiple different levels you can look into PROC ANOVA instead. The only two level variable in the data you've shown is EducationPreference.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your fast response! basically what I am trying to find is does a higher teacher satisfaction score yield higher grades? If the TTEST is not the right step to do this do you have any recommendations? Thanks